# How to reference a row in a different sheet to compute sums

Tags: excel

The sheet I want to reference is generated separately and cannot be modified.  It contains names of people and their respective numbers.  This sheet is called 'Finish'.  In a separate modifiable sheet called 'Tracker' I would like to reference back to 'Finish', find the person and use their row value to compute multiple columns of data.

I have tried `=MATCH('Finish'!"*name*",$A1:$A100,0)` however this code doesn't work.  I was going to then use that MATCH value in an INDIRECT function.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the row number of the (first) appearance of `*name*` in column A in the sheet Finish you should write your formula like:

```
=MATCH("*name*", Finish!A:A, 0)
```

In order to sum values in the row found by the `Match` function, say from column B to column E, you would need to use a formula like:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Finish!B" & MATCH("*name*", Finish!A:A, 0) & ":E" & MATCH("*name*", Finish!A:A, 0)))
```

Comment: ah thanks. How do I go about embedding the INDIRECT function in a SUMIF in order to sum the person's values in their row?